# How to reset BIOS on ASUS A46C Series

Tags: boot, laptop, motherboard, bios, asus-laptop

My laptop BIOS couldn't detect the harddisk drive. 
I've tried to load the default setting on BIOS, and remove the laptop battery then press power button for 30 seconds, but the issue remain the same. 
I also have tried to update the bios version but again no result.
I couldn't find the CMOS battery on the mainboard, probably the BIOS runs without CMOS battery.

Please help.

Comment: Is the hard drive internal or external? Have you got it to work before?

Comment: It's internal hard drive, the hdd is working properly, I checked it using ubuntu bootable CD.

Comment: There should be an option to restore the default configuration settings.  Of course I am not sure how that is going to help.  It sounds like you have more then just a configuration problem.  Your device has a CMOS battery otherwise if you took out the battery and unplugged the AC adapter the configurations would have been lost.